# Qual utilidade real do SqliteOpenHelper no Android?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Estava vendo um curso da devmedia online explicando sobre Sqlite no Android, no exemplo do curso foi feito um crud básico, foram criadas 1 banco e 2 tabelas.
No exemplo, estava criando duas classes que estendiam a SqliteOpenHelper, e cada classe manipulava uma tabela, ou seja, o exemplo estava usando o SqliteOpenHelper para gerenciar o banco e dados das tabelas!!

Depois de pesquisar por fora, vi que quando se cria o banco, o sqlite gera o cache dele, o que poderia gerar um grande problema neste caso do exemplo. E vi um exemplo de um site que foi usado uma classe separada para manipular as tabelas!

- Então estou confuso, o SqliteOpenHelper serve somente para criar o banco?
- Não se deve manipular dados das tabelas por ele (criando várias classes do SqliteOpenHelper, para cada tabela)?
- Se ele serve somente para gerenciar o banco (sem as tabelas), eu teria que criar todas tabelas na mesma classe do SqliteOpenHelper? Neste caso, se um usuário remover alguma tabela, como ela retornaria?

Não tenho como enviar o link do devmedia, pois o acesso é somente para assinantes.

> Exemplo gerenciando tabelas fora do helper:
>   http://pplware.sapo.pt/smartphones-tablets/android/tutorial-utilizao-do-sqlite-no-android-parte-i/

Comment: Não conheco o uso de SQLite no Android mas conheço o histórico de cursos e artigos da DevMedia. Muitos são legais, ajudam mesmo. Mas já vi cada besteira também. E os leigos (a maioria de quem lê, óbvio) acham que é bom o que não é. Nada contra a dizer sobre este curso, apenas um alerta geral. Bom, na verdade qualquer um pode escrever besteira, eu posso fazer isto, então o alerta é mais amplo.

Comment: eu estive percebendo isso depois de notar várias bobeiras, que só fui perceber depois de pesquisar a fundo no Google. Pelo menos a minha pergunta serve de aviso, para prestarem atenção antes de assinarem algo.

Comment: Estive pesquisando, e parece que realmente a função do SqliteOpenHelper. é de apenas facilitar a criação do banco pelos métodos onCreate e onUpdate. Mas ainda assim estou em dúvida sobre as criações de tabelas, se todas devem ser criadas no SqliteOpenHelper, e manipuladas em outra classe

Comment: Eu acho que a ideia principal do `SQLiteOpenHelper` é a configuração inicial da aplicação (seja na primeira instalação, onde as tabelas ainda não foram criadas) quanto para evolução (upgrade e downgrade de versão de banco). Não se deve usar ele diretamente para consultas. Na documentação está claro isso ("A helper class to manage database creation and version management"). Acredito que para consultas em banco não se deve usar ele, o melhor a se fazer é usar `ContentProvider's`, `Cursor's` ou no máximo um `SQLiteDatabase` para consultas rápidas, se for algo assíncrono use um `CursorLoader`.

Comment: @Wakim se puder responder, para eu aceitar... Acho que não vai aparecer nenhuma resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu acho que a ideia principal do SQLiteOpenHelper é a configuração inicial da aplicação (seja na primeira instalação, onde as tabelas ainda não foram criadas) quanto para evolução (upgrade e downgrade de versão de banco).

Na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) está claro isso:

> A helper class to manage database creation and version management.

Não se deve usar ele diretamente para consultas, porque existem formas melhores para ser fazer isso.

O melhor a se fazer é usar [ContentProvider's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)/[ContentResolver's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html), [Cursor's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) ou no máximo um [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) para consultas rápidas. Se a ideia é fazer consultas assíncronas, use um [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html).

No pior dos casos, até um ORM é válido. Exemplos: [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml), [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/), [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/index.html) e o [Active Android](http://www.activeandroid.com/).

**Opinião pessoal:**
Eu costumo usar `CursorLoader`, `ContentProvider's` e `Cursor`. Tenho um app que usa o **Active Android**, mas se eu tivesse tempo de refazer, usaria de fato `CursorLoader` mesmo.

Não irei colocar exemplos de códigos porque senão fugirá muito do escopo da pergunta.